# Hotel - Can connect to network but not internet

Tags: networking, laptop, internet, netbook

I have an annoying problem with my netbook.  It's a Toshiba NB525.  My laptop can access the internet and connect wirelessly at home.

I'm currently staying at a hotel.  I can detect and connect to the network but no internet.

The way the internet at this hotel works is that it redirects you to a site to log in before gaining access.

It seems to work intermittently but very rarely.  Requiring me to reset the connection multiple times.  Problem is, my other devices work perfectly fine to connect.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm running windows 7 on the netbook.

Comment: Are you saying that the login process works intermittently, or that the connection in general is intermittent?

Answer (score 0):

Have you access to their net access? It sounds to me as if you may need to purchase that access. At least talk to the hotel and I'm sure they'll solve it.

Comment: Hi Xavierjazz,  You're right about paying for the access.  I've paid for it and it works intermittently... though rarely.  Oddly enough, my room mate has an ipad and it connects perfectly fine every time.  Same goes for my phone.  Grateful for any input.